# Apache PDFBox wrong acces permission

Tags: java, pdf, permissions, pdfbox

I'm trying to extract access permissions with Apache PDFBox. The problem is that all the permissions are set to true.
For example, I extracted the Document Assembly property as follow:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));
AccessPermission ap = doc.getCurrentAccessPermission();
boolean documentAssembly = ap.canAssembleDocument();
```

The documentAssembly variable is true. However, when i check the permissions on Adobe reader I found that the document assembly property is set to not allowed: [image]

Is there a way to extract all the correct informations, as in the above image?

Comment: Can you share the document? Maybe there are additional permissions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533786/535646 (IIRC this isn't supported by PDFBox)

Comment: Here it is: http://www.filedropper.com/provaafter

Comment: Part of the problem may be incorrect use of PDFBox.  Try this:
 PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));
 AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission(doc.getEncryptionDictionary().getPermissions());
 boolean documentAssembly = ap.canAssembleDocument();

Answer (score 2):

What you see on the security tab is a summary of all document restrictions that apply. In particular there are some restrictions which only depend on the PDF viewer you use. If I look at the same dialog in Adobe Acrobat (not Reader), for example, I see

[image: screen shot]

Obviously PDFBox does not know which viewer you will use. So it cannot consider viewer specific restrictions.

Comment: For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65021738/1729265).